# Serialization - Exclude certain properties/columns from the instance/object of a User Entity in Nestjs and TypeORM

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have an API to my nestjs application to return a list of users from the database. I use TypeORM.

I have a `user.controller.ts`, `user.service.ts` and a `User.entity.ts`.

I have a method called `findAll()` inside user service. When I call that method in my controller. it's gonna return an `Promise<UserEntity[]>` and then the controller sends the respons next to the frontend.

Now, I want to be able to exclude some properties like (password, accessToken, etc). How can I do that and what is the correct way of doing it?

user.controller.ts

```
@Controller("user")
export class UserController {
    constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}

    @Get()
    public getUsers(): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
        return this.userService.findAll();
    }
}
```

user.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    public constructor(@InjectRepository(UserEntity) private userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>) {}

    public async findAll(): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
        return await this.userRepository.find();
    }
}
```

user.entity.ts

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, CreateDateColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity({ name: "users" })
export class UserEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    name: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    age: number;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    accessToken: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    lastActive: string;

    @CreateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp", default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" })
    createdAt: Date;

    @CreateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp", default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", onUpdate: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" })
    updatedAt: Date;
}
```

PS: In Laravel I know i could make something like a Resource to get a result  similar to what I want here.

Answer (score 0):

Use exclude field on column in userEntity from class-transformer since typeorm uses it behind the scenes

```
@Column({ select: false })
@Exclude()
password: string;
```

Comment: I did that and it still shows the password (column/property).

Comment: Yea my bad i edited my answer try the new version @Galbert

Comment: Yes, but using { select: false } is only for query builder